# Drawing polygon and change the color

Tags: android

I wrote code as you see below to draw Polygon but does not drawing and displaying on map why ? 
Can you check and tell me
Please help
Thank you....

```
public class Map extends  Activity implements OnMapClickListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

 FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
 myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
 myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 myMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);


@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) { 
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
         new LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
         new LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
         new LatLng(37.35, -122.2),
         new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));

//Get back the mutable Polygon
Polygon polygon = myMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing the polygon at a very specific point on the map (somewhere in Sunnyvale California). Is it possible that when you are testing this code you are not looking at Sunnyvale?

Also the default fill color of a polygon is transparent (default stroke color is black). You can set the fill color by calling the fillColor method on the PolygonOptions object before adding the polygon to the map.

If you want a polygon to draw where you click the map, you'll have to use the LatLng point that's passed in as a parameter to your onMapClick function to determine how to draw the polygon.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes

EDIT:

Here's some code that will draw a polygon whose center is a the point the map was clicked with width 0.1 degrees of latitude/longitude. (I haven't tested this though)

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) { 
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(point.lat() - 0.05, point.lng() - 0.05),
         new LatLng(point.lat() + 0.05, point.lng() - 0.05),
         new LatLng(point.lat() + 0.05, point.lng() + 0.05),
         new LatLng(point.lat() - 0.05, point.lng() + 0.05),
         new LatLng(point.lat() - 0.05, point.lng() - 0.05));
    //Optionally call fillColor(Color.BLUE) or whatever color you want
    myMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
}
```

Comment: Can you write it please because I did not know how to write it